# My sample app didn't run because of this? Any one here can help me?

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

Add below line to your gradel app in defaultConfig.

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

its helpfull for you.

Comment: i already did sir., but still the same., i'll tried a new app., without anything just "hello world"., but still the same

Comment: Restart your android studio and then try again.

Comment: finished with non-zero exit value 1... The other question here is VALUE 2. what is the difference ?